# Extending Python: pre-load my C module

Tags: python, c, import, python-c-api, python-embedding

I'm trying to extend Python interpreter by a few C functions I wrote. From reading docs, to expose those function the user has to import the module encompassing the functions.

Is it possible to load pre-load or pre-import via C API the module so that the user doesn't have to type `import <mymodule>`? Or even better, `from <mymodule> import <function>`?

**Edit:** I can do PyRun_SimpleString("from mymodule import myfunction") just after Py_Initialize(); - I was just wondering if there is another way of doing this..?

**Edit 2:** In other words, I have an application written in C which embeds a Python interpreter. That application provides some functionality which I want to expose to the users so they can write simple Python scripts for the app. All I want is to remove the need of writing `from mymodule import myfunction1, myfunction2` because, since it is very specialized app and the script wont work without the app anyway, it doesn't make sense to require to `import ...` all the time.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Just why?

Comment: "so that the user doesn't have to type import <mymodule>"

Comment: Based upon your edits, it's a script, so you can add `from mymodule import ...` in the script.  No one needs to type that anymore then.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you implement a module in Python, the user would have to `import` it. This is the way Python works, and it's actually *a good thing* - it's one of the great pluses of Python - the namespace/module system is robust, easy to use and simple to understand.

For academic exercises only, you could of course add your new functionality to Python itself, by creating a custom interpreter. You could even create new keywords this way. But for any practical purpose, this isn't recommended.

Answer (score 3):

In general, no.  But if your users are only going to be using your module in interactive sessions, and you can set their environmental variables, you can set the [PYTHONSTARTUP environmental variable](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#the-interactive-startup-file) to a script to run when an interactive session is started.

The only case I can think of, is if you and your group are using python for data analysis, have custom commands for your particular problem, and most users are more scientists/statisticians than programmers.  But even in that case, I'd suggest using IPython, creating an [IPython profile](http://ipython.scipy.org/doc/manual/html/config/overview.html#profiles), and then creating an alias/script for the users to run.  It's cleaner, and the different name warns them that they aren't using the default Python environment.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, set your [`PYTHONSTARTUP`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP) environment variable to point to a file.  In `sh`, `ksh`, `bash` etc., you can do:

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pystartup
export PYTHONSTARTUP
```

Then, you can put statements and code in your `$PYTHONSTARTUP` file:

```
echo "import blah" >>$PYTHONSTARTUP
```

That should do it.  It will work only for interactive sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You could add it to the Python interpreter itself, but that would mean creating a custom Python version, which, I guess, is not what you want.

That `import <mymodule>` is not just for loading the module, it's also for making this module visible in the (main|current) namespace. Being able to do that, w/o hacking the actual Python interpreter, would run against "Explicit is better than implicit" very strongly.

Comment: Current namespace is probably a dict, right? So it could be somehow possible to find that dict and AddItem() my function to it...?

Comment: @EricH - even if it's possible in some hackish way, DON'T DO IT. It's not idiomatic in Python, not what users would expect and generally a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this blog post on how to pre-import modules in embedded python.

> [Embed Python and Import Modules in C/C++](http://blog.dmaggot.org/2009/12/embed-python-and-import-modules-in-cc/)

For example to simulate the following statement in Python:

```
from hashlib import md5, sha1
```

We do in C:

```
PyObject * subModules = PyList_New(0);
PyList_Append(subModules, PyString_FromString("md5"));
PyList_Append(subModules, PyString_FromString("sha1"));
PyObject * hashlibImports = PyImport_ImportModuleEx("hashlib", NULL, NULL, subModules);
PyObject * md5Module = PyObject_GetAttr(hashlibImports, PyString_FromString("md5"));
PyObject * sha1Module = PyObject_GetAttr(hashlibImports, PyString_FromString("sha1"));
PyObject * mainModule = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
PyModule_AddObject(mainModule, "md5", md5Module);
PyModule_AddObject(mainModule, "sha1", sha1Module);
```

Also here is a link to [relevant code](https://github.com/dMaggot/QGLFlush/blob/master/src/qglflushvisualizer.cpp#L24) from the project mentioned in the article which basically performs:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
```

after Python initialization.